# Do a wildcard filter of branch names

Tags: git

`git branch --all` lists lots of branches, and I am looking for one that includes the string `1234`, which is an issue number in our project management system.

The following works in PowerShell and I am wanting to replace it with something shell agnostic.

```
PS> git branch --all | where { $_ -like "*1234*" }
```

How do we do this with `git` and `git` alone?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`git branch --list "*1234*"` does what you need.  Or `git branch --list \*1234\*`

Comment: Add in `-r` for remote. That wasn't required by the OP.