# Filter git branches using wild card

Tags: git, github

I am trying to list all the branches that contains 'feature' in it. 
Before posting this here I have referred to the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33400972/do-a-wildcard-filter-of-branch-names/33401085#)

The solutions provided there does not work for me - ie; `git branch --list "*feature*"` or `git branch --list \*feature\*`

It does not return a list of branches as expected when I try from terminal. Can someone please let me know what can be the reason and possible solutions, if any.

End goal is to delete all the branches returned as part of the list

Comment: Just tested on a local git repo, and the following works for me: `git branch --list 'test*'`. Are the branches local?

Comment: no..they are all remote branches to which I have access to

Answer (score 7):

I have the following branches locally:

```
git branch --list
  1test
  2test
  3test
* master
  t1
  t2
  t3
  test1
  test2
  test3
  test4
```

This command will search for *local* branches with the name `test*` and delete them:

```
git branch --list 'test*' --format '%(refname:short)' | xargs git branch -d
Deleted branch test1 (was fca79ef34c04).
Deleted branch test2 (was fca79ef34c04).
Deleted branch test3 (was fca79ef34c04).
Deleted branch test4 (was fca79ef34c04).
```

---

By default `--list` will only show local branches. You can see in the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#_description) that you can provide `-r` to only show remote branches, or `-a` to show both remote and local branches. Let's update the previous command to work for remote branches.

```
git branch --list 'test*' -r --format '%(refname:short)' | xargs git push -d origin
```

You could also try using the command with the full ref:

```
git branch --list 'test*' -r --format '%(refname)' | xargs git push -d origin
```

Comment: So based on git documentation, you mean to say git branch --list 'test*' -r will give me a list of remote branches which has test in their names?

Comment: Yes that is correct. You may want to use `*test*` if you have something prefixing it.

Comment: git branch --list 'feature/*' -r does not give me a list of remote branches which starts with feature/  . Any reasons?

Comment: Just updated my answer. The last snippet uses the full ref. You may need to do a `git fetch` so your local repo is aware of the branches.

Comment: @user264953 Have you tried ` git branch --list -r "*feature/*" ` ? What is the output you are getting ? If its not working, what is your git version ?

Comment: @vishnunarayanan - git branch --list -r "feature/" doesn't work either - I am not shown the remote branches list. My git version 2.8.1.windows.1

Comment: Sorry,my bad. Have you tried the regex version \*feature/\*? ` git branch --list -r "\*feature/\*" `

Answer (score 2):

To list all branches (local and remote) that contain 'feature': 
`git branch --all --list "*feature*"`

To list only remote branches that contain 'feature': 
`git branch --remotes --list "origin/*feature*"`

As Jim [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49238118/filter-git-branches-using-wild-card/49238397#49238397), `git branch --format '%(refname)'` outputs the full refname of each branch.

So putting it together, if OP wants to try deleting all remote branches starting with 'feature/' from the server: 
`git branch -rl "origin/feature/*" --format "%(refname)" | xargs git push --dry-run -d origin`

⚠️ Remove `--dry-run` only after confirming the list of branches.

---

Notes:

- OP's initial solution didn't work without `--all` because the branches are remote.
- The suggestions with `-r, --remotes` didn't work because remote branch names take the form `<remote>/<branch>` ([git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)); therefore, the pattern needs to start with the name of the remote, e.g. `origin/` (though vishnu's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49238118/filter-git-branches-using-wild-card#comment85520288_49238397) did work by starting the pattern with `*`)
- The output is slightly different for `-a` vs. `-r`.

```
# Example: feature/{foo,new} are local, and feature/{foo,bar,baz} are all remote

$ git branch -al "*feature*"
  feature/foo
  feature/new
  remotes/origin/feature/bar
  remotes/origin/feature/baz
  remotes/origin/feature/foo
# ^^ remote branches are qualifed with 'remotes/' prefix

$ git branch -rl "origin/*feature*"
  origin/feature/bar
  origin/feature/baz
  origin/feature/foo
# ^^ branches are known to be remote, so prefix 'remotes/' is dropped

$ git branch -rl "origin/feature/*" --format "%(refname)"
refs/remotes/origin/feature/bar
refs/remotes/origin/feature/baz
refs/remotes/origin/feature/foo
# ^^ full refnames start with 'refs/'

$ git branch -rl "origin/feature/*" --format "%(refname)" | xargs git push --dry-run -d origin
To github.com:foo1-org/foo1.git
 - [deleted]         origin/feature/bar
 - [deleted]         origin/feature/baz
 - [deleted]         origin/feature/foo
```